# Why does GHC print 15-tuples but not 16-tuples?

Tags: haskell

Why does this work

```
print (True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True)
```

while this does not

```
print (True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True)
```

Comment: There must be a more suitable data structure for you than a 16-tuple? This is just out of curiosity?

Comment: @AndrewC I was modeling a 16-bit adder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because there is `Show` instance for 15-tuple:

```
Prelude> :i (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
data (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,) a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
  = (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,) a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
    -- Defined in `GHC.Tuple'
<<skip>>
instance (Read a, Read b, Read c, Read d, Read e, Read f, Read g,
          Read h, Read i, Read j, Read k, Read l, Read m, Read n, Read o) =>
         Read (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o)
  -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
instance (Show a, Show b, Show c, Show d, Show e, Show f, Show g,
          Show h, Show i, Show j, Show k, Show l, Show m, Show n, Show o) =>
         Show (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o)
  -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
```

And there are no for 16-tuple:

```
Prelude> :i (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
data (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,) a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
  = (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,) a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
    -- Defined in `GHC.Tuple'
```

See [docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Text-Show.html)

AFAIK instances are hand-written somethere in ghc internal libraries, and it is unlikely anybody will need to show 16-tuple.

Comment: If you're interested in the source, the datatypes are [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/src/GHC-Tuple.html), the Read instances are [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.1.0/doc/html/src/GHC-Read.html#line-555), and the Show instances are [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.3.2/doc/html/src/GHC-Show.html#line-216). Apparently if you do too many of these definitions then GHC eventually segfaults, so it has to end somewhere.

Comment: @JeffreyBurka thanks. I tried to find sources in docs for the latest three versions of base on hackage, but links to `GHC.Show` don't work. Re `GHC.Tuple`: I tried up to 850-tuple, and `ghci` knows about all of them.

Comment: So it does. Those can't be defined anywhere though, so what's going on there?

Answer (score 7):

This is defined in the Haskell Report [Section 6.1.4 Tuples](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#basic-tuples):

> There is no upper bound on the size of a tuple, but some Haskell implementations may restrict the size of tuples, and limit the instances associated with larger tuples. However, every Haskell implementation must support tuples up to size 15, together with the instances for Eq, Ord, Bounded, Read, and Show. The Prelude and libraries define tuple functions such as zip for tuples up to a size of 7.